# Cannot find declaration to go in Rider Razor project

Tags: intellij-idea, razor, rider

I've cloned a repository that include .cshtml and DLL files but it's hard to be productive when right click + ctrl shows the message above and doesn't go anywhere.

Also Intellisense doesn't work when trying to get suggestions from C# methods.

I've tried to clear caches by clicking Invalidate Caches or deleting .idea folders but to no avail.

Wonder how I should proceed to get this to work.

Thanks for your help

I've tried to add a .csproj file to the project and when building the solution I get this error:

"FrontendTemplates.csproj: [MSB4057] The target "Build" does not exist in the project."

I changed the original file to have a minimal one for now before trying to build everything:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')"/>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')"/>
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <RootNamespace>MyProject</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MyProject</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp"/>
<Reference Include="System"/>
<Reference Include="System.Data"/>
<Reference Include="System.Drawing"/>
<Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData"/>
<Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices"/>
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations"/>
<Reference Include="System.Core"/>
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions"/>
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq"/>
<Reference Include="System.Web"/>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions"/>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Abstractions"/>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Routing"/>
<Reference Include="System.Xml"/>
<Reference Include="System.Configuration"/>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Services"/>
<Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices"/>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <Private>True</Private>
    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http">
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest">
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <Private>True</Private>
    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <Private>True</Private>
    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Optimization">
    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <Private>True</Private>
    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <Private>True</Private>
    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <Private>True</Private>
    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <Private>True</Private>
    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
    <HintPath>packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="WebGrease">
    <Private>True</Private>
    <HintPath>packages\WebGrease.1.6.0\lib\WebGrease.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime">
    <Private>True</Private>
    
<HintPath>packages\Antlr.3.5.0.2\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform">
    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that you have opened the repository as a folder as opposed to a .NET project? Try File | Open Project and select a .csproj file.

Comment: That may be one of the issues, there isn't a .csproj file there. I've tried to create a new empty solution, attach the repository folder, build solution but it says no loaded projects. How should I proceed to properly create a Razor project in Rider?

Comment: Hmm, why would anyone not commit a .csproj into a repository?..

Try creating a new project in Rider from an ASP.NET Core template, copy the generated .csproj over into your cloned project, and open it as a project using the new .csproj.

Comment: Edited my question with the csproj file settings.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a .NET Framework (v4.8) project but your machine doesn't have the version of MSBuild required to do so.

Please check what version of .NET Framework or .NET Core SDK you have installed on your machine (specifically, here's how you can figure out what MSBuild versions you have available: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/04/13/introducing-jetbrains-redistributable-msbuild/) and use a .csproj file format that is supported by that version.

Comment: I've downloaded the Jetbrains MSBuild, selected it from the options in Rider but still seeing the same error. If the ToolsVersion says 15.0 and the MSBuild is the same version where is the error coming from? What is not matching? Added a screenshot with the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Would one of [Workarounds from RIDER-87113](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-87113) help?

The first one is simply preventing imports of targets if they are absent in .csproj file:

```
<Import Project="..\..\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets')" />
```

Like the example above, but with the specific for the project paths to .targets.

Another way is trying to install the Web Components from the Visual Studio using a native installer ([workaround from RIDER-87113](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-87113) as well):

> 1. Select an instance of Visual Studio in VS installer and click "Modify";
> 2. In the opened window, select "ASP.NET and Web Development" in "Workloads" tab and install it;
> 3. After installing, in Rider under *Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolset & Build select* MSBuild from the Visual Studio
>    where you installed this workload;
> 4. Try to load and build your project.